# Laravel call to member function create() on a non-object

Tags: php, relationship, factory, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to seed a database using some model factories but I'm getting error `call to member function create() on a non-object`

Below are my model factories:

```
$factory->define(App\Organisation::class, function ($faker) {
   return [
    'name' => $faker->company,
   ];
});

$factory->define(App\Department::class, function ($faker) {
   return [
    'name' => $faker->catchPhrase,
    'organisation_id' => factory(App\Organisation::class)->make()->id,
   ];
});

$factory->define(App\User::class, function ($faker) {
  return [
    'email' => $faker->email,
    'password' => str_random(10),
    'organisation_id' => factory(App\Organisation::class)->make()->id,
    'remember_token' => str_random(10),
  ];
});
```

In my seeder I'm using the following to create 2 organizations and a associate a user and a department to each organization and then to make a user the manager of that department:

```
factory(App\Organisation::class, 2)
        ->create()
        ->each(function ($o)
        {
            $user = $o->users()->save(factory(App\User::class)->make());

            $department = $o->departments()->save(factory(App\Department::class)->make());

            $department->managedDepartment()->create([
                'organisation_id' => $o->id,
                'manager_id' => $user->id,
            ]);


        });
```

However I'm getting fatalerrorexception `call to member function create() on a non-object`

I thought `$department` is an object?

My department model is as follows:

```
class Department extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['name','organisation_id'];

    public function organisation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Organisation');
    }

    /* a department is managed by a user */
    public function managedDepartment()
    {
       $this->hasOne('App\ManagedDepartment');
    }
}
```

And my managedDepartment model is as follows:

```
class ManagedDepartment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'managed_departments';


    protected $fillable = ['organisation_id', 'department_id', 'manager_id',];


    public function department()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\Department');
    }

    public function manager()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to return your relation

```
    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Department');
    }
```

And here

```
 /* a department is managed by a user */
    public function managedDepartment()
    {
       return $this->hasOne('App\ManagedDepartment');
    }
```

I think it will resolve your problem.

Comment: well spotted. Adding return fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not make foreign keys fillable!
Secondly, where is your organisation function in ManagedDepartment? You should create one, otherwise the following will not work, because association is not possible.
Thirdly, I think you should change make() to create() in the following

```
$factory->define(App\Organisation::class, function ($faker) {
   return [
    'name' => $faker->company,
   ];
});

$factory->define(App\Department::class, function ($faker) {
   return [
    'name' => $faker->catchPhrase,
    'organisation_id' => factory(App\Organisation::class)->create()->id,
   ];
});

$factory->define(App\User::class, function ($faker) {
  return [
    'email' => $faker->email,
    'password' => str_random(10),
    'organisation_id' => factory(App\Organisation::class)->create()->id,
    'remember_token' => str_random(10),
  ];
});
```

Furthermore:

```
factory(App\Organisation::class, 2)
    ->create()
    ->each(function ($o)
    {
        $user = factory(App\User::class)->create();
        $o->users()->attach($user->id);

        $department = factory(App\Department::class)->create();
        $o->departments()->attach($department);

        $managedDep = new ManagedDepartment();
        $managedDep->associate($o);
        $managedDep->associate($user);
        $managedDep->associate($department);
        $managedDep->save();
    });
```

Comment: Your code is another solution. ozzii code  written like in docs.